# How to cache spring application context for me to use it across many JVM's

Tags: java, spring, caching, executable-jar

I got 4 stand alone java programs inside a jar... Its a jar of spring 3.0.5 + Maven project...Here is my requirement

1) The first java program will load the spring application context.

How to make that application context available to the other stand alone java programs when they are invoked? **Each of them runs in their own JVM** and I am thinking there is a need for me to save the application context in some sort of cache? and each of those programs will retrieve the application context when they need it and update the context back into the cache

**I cannot load the application context in each of those programs...**

Please help me here on whether my thought process is correct or is there any other solution?

Comment: This almost certainly sounds like the wrong approach. Can you explain a bit more why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (or at least it isn't a good idea) to attempt to share a Spring application context across multiple applications. That is why it as called an "application context" it defines the objects that interact in a single application.

I would restructure your application context into 4 smaller application contexts for the 4 different applications, if they are indeed different applications.

Another alternative, is to adjust your design so that the first application exposes an interface (RMI or REST or some other RPC mechanism) so that the other 3 applications can interact with the first. This should be the last resort, as it is much more complex.

Comment: ok...Let me elaborate a bit more.... i dont have a server. Its stand alone .. so i cant host a service.. Also they are not different applications...its only one application...there are scripts that would call these programs repeatedly...and i need to start the app context separately in order to create and maintain a thread pool.. All those individual java programs that get called every time  must be part of that thread pool. Does that make sense?

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't have a server. Your first application could start up Jetty or Netty or a simple socket server if you want to write your own. RMI is the more "standard" approach to this sort of thing if you really need 4 different Java applications to talk to each other. Spring supports remoting through RMI. You still wouldn't be sharing the same application context in this situation.

Comment: So let me see if I understand this. You have scripts that periodically submit jobs that should be executed in the same thread pool? And you want to keep the application context loaded the whole time, for efficiency reasons and so that the jobs can share infrastructure?

Comment: thanks for explaining this to me... I was dumb... I dont need a thread pool at all... I can let all the programs individually...+1 everywhere for trying to help me